# What Stackexchange site is for questions about small appliances?

Tags: discussion

The Home Improvement site specifically lists questions about repairing small appliances as off topic. They certainly don't seem on topic here. Which Stackexchage site covers small appliances?

Comment: Not much comes to mind, I wrote [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196118/203972) to a similar question on Meta.SO a while back and didn't get any comments that I'd missed some site. It might be OK here if you can meet the criteria I've put there.

Comment: I think there should be a niche for it. I'll start an Area51 proposal for such a site to see if there is interest.

Comment: Worth a shot, there was an appliance repair question I wouldn't have minded asking recently but was OT for here because it was related to the mechanical side of things.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't (yet) a StackExchange (SE) site for appliance repair.

Although I am just speculating here, one main reason is that repairing appliances can require knowledge from many disciplines: electrical, mechanical, thermodynamics, etc. It's difficult in the scope of SE to gauge someone's knowledge or ability when asking a general repair question.

One reason that the Electronics SE <strike>bans</strike> closes many repair questions is that generally such questions are very broad and are not formatted in a way that shows the OP has narrowed the problem down to anything specific. There is no way to provide an answer in a concise and accurate manner that explains to someone how to troubleshoot an electronic device when, presumably, they do not have experience with digital circuit troubleshooting, know how to use an oscilloscope, etc.

Another problem that arises with repair of appliances is, quite simply, the danger of it: Mains voltages; high voltages (in the case of CRT's for example); heating elements; water in proximity to electrical systems; mechanical assemblies involving gears, motors, pumps, etc.; and all manner of other things which range from barely on-topic to very off-topic. Again, it's difficult or impossible to know if the OP has experience with any of these and SE answers are not supposed to be a repair manual in and of themselves.

That said, questions *can* be about repair, but they need to be specific. If you're repairing a small appliance, say a microwave oven, and you are knowledgeable and comfortable doing so, it's much more likely that a question you would ask here has to do with a specific part or circuit in the course of your repair.

If you ask "How can I fix my microwave?" and provide a few details like, "It makes some noises and turns off before the time limit..." it becomes obvious that you're probably not qualified to actually attempt a repair. Nobody is going to want to write the necessary ***books*** to properly teach the skills necessary and post it in the SE context. (Let alone the OP reading it all.)

Say you narrow down the problem to the circuit that times the oven, take measurements at various spots and think you've found an incorrect voltage, perhaps you even have a good idea which component(s) are at fault. *Even then* it's difficult for anyone to help, because they *don't have access* to the boards and their bench. It winds up being a conversation instead of a Q&A: "Did you check for a square wave at the output of the clock?" "Yes, but it was 1.2 volts instead of 5 like I expected." "That might be a problem with the other widget. Go measure that." ... And so on.

I think you get the idea. Repair questions are often very broad. If you are an experienced engineer, and know about the device you are repairing (and even have service manuals), chances are you're not likely to ask SE. But if you do run into some engineering question in the course of performing a repair, such a question would probably be welcome (and might not even need to mention that it's part of a repair).